# How to open a URL via UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with five static cells.

I'm trying to make it so when I tap one of the cells, it opens a specific URL. Each cell has its own unique URL.

How can I do this?

Using Swift 3, Xcode.

Thanks!

**Code:**

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class SettingsTableView: UITableViewController {

    @IBAction func clearCache(_ sender: Any) {


        ImageCache.default.clearMemoryCache()

        ImageCache.default.clearDiskCache()

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]

        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false

    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Use- `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

//your code...

}`

Comment: @iDeveloper I'm not sure I understand. Could you please post the code as a response? Thank you.

Comment: You want to open URL, by click on tableViewCell?

Comment: @Miles http://stackoverflow.com/a/39637130/6433023 Check this one

Comment: So simply get indexPath of selected item and action perform

Comment: @NiravD Thanks for the link. Doesn't seem to be working. "Value of type 'SettingsTableView' has no member 'urlArray'

Comment: @Miles Instead of `let url =  URL(string: self.urlArray[indexPath.row])!` you need to generate your URL on the depending of that 5 static cell that you have told.

Answer (score 4):

Simply implement `UITableViewDelegate` method **`didSelectRowAt`** and open the url from the array of urls for corresponding selected row of the `UITableView`.

```
let urlArray = ["http://google.com", "https://apple.com"]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let urlString = self.urlArray[indexPath.row]
        if let url = URL(string: urlString)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `didSelectRowAt indexPath` function, you will have to call `open` instead of `openURL`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let url =  URL(string: self.urlArray[indexPath.row])!
     UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a `var urlToBeOpened : String` property in the custom cell class that you are dequeuing.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
               let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
               let urlAsString = cell.urlToBeOpened
               let url = URL(string : urlAsString)
               UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)

}
```

Make sure that the `urlToBeOpened` string it URL Encoded or `URL(string : urlAsString)` will return nil

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global array (inside your class) with links like that

```
let links = ["http://google.com", "https://apple.com"]
```

Then in **didSelectRowAt** simply open your link

```
let link = links[indexPath.row]
if let url = URL(string: link){
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}  //else you entered an incorrect link
```